# why is apipie documentation route not found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, documentation, apipie

After following the *getting started* steps of [Apipie](https://github.com/Apipie/apipie-rails):

1. echo "gem 'apipie-rails'" >> Gemfile
2. bundle install
3. rails g apipie:install

And documenting a controller like this:

```
api :GET, '/users/:id'
param :id, :number, desc: 'id of the requested user'
def show
  # ...
end
```

I got the following routing error when accessing the route **/apipie**:

**Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/apipie"**

Answer (score 0):

Apipie requires having an API route called **apipie** in the **routes.rb** ruby on rails file. The solution that worked for me is to manually add this line to **routes.rb** along side any other routes in the project:

```
#config/routes.rb
...
apipie #required gem route
get 'profile', to: 'users#show' #example route
...
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).